# How long would it take people to realise some rabbits are sapient?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, fauna, fantasy-races

Set in modern day, a small warren of rabbits randomly achieve sapience in an unremarkable, rural countryside. These rabbits become capable of thinking and self-reflection, as well as advanced teamworking and organisation. They could use tools, but its difficult to craft or hold anything with paws. Otherwise, they live as rabbits live.
They are incapable of speaking any human language (incompatible vocal cords), but they do have a language of their own.

Although intelligent, they are still unlearnt and their society is primitive.

Any offspring from this warren is sapient as well, but all other rabbits remain just animals. The warren is capable of expanding at however fast rabbits breed.

Rabbit hunting and snaring is still popular among the farmers living nearby the rabbit's territory. As such, the rabbits develop a deep fear of humans and try to avoid them.

How long would it take humans to realise that this rabbit community possesses sapience?

Comment: The first time one of the little honkers jumped onto my chest, grabbed my shirt, and cussed me out - and just after I overcame my shock over being cussed out by a rabbit - I'd realize the ittle hasenpfeffer-on-the-hoof was sentient.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong (in which case I probably misunderstood the question), but I think you're all confusion sentient with sapient. Now that I think about it, I've pointed out this same mistake quite a few times on this website...

Comment: You're right, I am. I've edited it to sapient instead of sentient.

Comment: A first glance, your rabbits == Watership Down's rabbits.  (In case there are any intellectual property concerns.)

Comment: Lol, yes. The question was Watership Down inspired.

Comment: Even real-world rabbits can understand some human words that are of interest for them (hay, carrot, breakfast) and of course their names. Sapient rabbits could easily spy on the humans around. Rabbits are small, silent and can hear very much better than us.

Comment: If they start weaving baskets and raising hens for their eggs...

Comment: They film an autobiographical documentary, and call it "watership down". Realistically, with the sort of life they live?? mass society collapse, neurosis and suicides. Being Rabbit is ***tough***. The very last thing you want is a brain to be able to realize just what a raw deal you have.

Answer (score 8):

**A lot longer than you might think, followed by no time at all**

Sapience is more than the ability to think grand thoughts.  It's the ability to work with and around your environment.  To plan for your future beyond simple food storage (chipmunks ain't sapient, nasty little bounders when they're throwing stuff at my cat, but not sapient).  A sapient creature consistently acts proactively.

Which means humans would rarely (if ever) see them.

Sapient rabbits would quickly realize they're a food source for other creatures, most notably wolves and humans.  The easiest way to protect themselves would be to not be where the predator is.  So their warrens (if they even used them anymore) wouldn't be near human encampments.

However, once you did find them, you'd notice odd things, like guards and basic built-up defenses or early-warning stuff like well-placed twigs that make predictable popping noises when disturbed.

So, I think it would take forever and a day (or some blindingly bad luck on the part of the rabbits) to discover the rabbits, but a short time after that to realize they were sapient.  What rabbit carries a knife or any other form of tool?

Comment: Chipmunks are definitely sentient (as are pretty much all animals, with the exception perhaps of insects and bivalves and such, the latter questions not having been answered conclusively one way or the other) if you're using the standard (though, yes language is an evolving construct) definition of sentient, which is simply the capacity to perceive/experience. Perhaps you mean self-aware (which is broadly the capacity to understand one's relation to the world and to oneself)?

Comment: @AngelPray are you trying to drive me mad????  They can't... I mean they just *can't* be sentient.  The evil little proto-monkies!  *They hate my cat!*  They can't... No... it's OK.  They're not sentient.  It's still OK to shoot the fat little rats.  (whew!  that was close!)

Comment: @JBH Sentinet is actually has a much broader biological definition than what we often think of, mostly because poeple confuse it with sapient. that is what Angelpray is referencing. in biology sentient more or less boils down to "has a brain" if you live outside the eastern US gray squirrels are invasive so kill them to your satisfaction.

Comment: “(chipmunks ain't sapient, nasty little bounders when they're throwing stuff at my cat, but not sentient)” Did you mean ARE sapient? This sentence as written does not parse.

Comment: @SRM, nope.  Expressed in book English: "Chipmunks are not sapient.  Even though they throw things at my cat, which suggests some level of intelligence, they simply aren't sapient."  It's an in-joke for anyone who's ever had a pet terrorized by chipmunks, which can throw pine cones with remarkable accuracy.  Evil little communists....

Comment: Actually, they might not be as skittish as you are picturing.  They very well might figure out that there are multiple types of humans.  Yes, farmers would be dangerous, but hikers would not.  And they wouldn't realize there would be a reaction to being discovered to be sapient.  Thus I would expect discovery much sooner due to a hiker or photographer with a long lens.

Comment: @LorenPechtel, that's possible, but the OP described a primitive society.  My after-the-answer opinion is that the analysis you're suggesting might be complicated.  Not all hikers are nice people.

Comment: @JBH Then why use the contraction “but”? It should be “and” if they are neither sentient nor sapient.

Comment: @JBH While I am sure there are a few bad apples in my experience they don't get much beyond the trailheads.  In the backcountry most everybody is good.

Comment: Will the people arguing about **sapience** please make sure they understand the difference between **sapience** and **sentience**. Otherwise you only *think* you are arguing.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica (a) Hopefully you noticed the dates (2018). Yours was the first addition to the argument in 2-1/2 years. (b) Sentient (adj) "able to perceive or feel things." (c) Sapient (adj) (1) "wise, or attempting to appear wise." (2) "relating to the human species." (d) If you read my 2nd comment, "It's an in-joke for anyone who's ever had a pet terrorized by chipmunks."

Answer (score 6):

**Probably not long at all**

The population numbers would explode, as noted by kineticcrusher.  Sapient rabbits would suddenly be much harder to kill as they would be better able to learn from the mistakes of fellow rabbits and avoid traps, bait, spotlighting farmers, birds of prey etc.

However, sapience does not equate to knowledgeable.  There is also no guarantee that sapient rabbit ethics are even close to (any) human ethics.  If they are in a rural area then they will go for the crops on hand because they are the most available food source and they will not understand the consequences that will follow.  Their psychology will probably allow them to accept casualty levels, even among their young, that humans today would consider unacceptable.

The farmers will detect massive increased rabbit feeding damaging their crops.  They will try all the usual remedies and fail to solve the problem - each attempt will cause some casualties, but *all* the survivors and their descendants will learn how to deal with the new threat.  The most likely escalation is that the farmers call in the state or federal primary industry body or some experts from the university.  This results in a study, involving drones and remote cameras.  The rabbits would quickly learn that the cameras are not a threat and act "sapient normal" in their view, at which point the secret is out.

Alternatively, if the rabbits are in Australia then we might try out a new strain of [calicivirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_haemorrhagic_disease) on the feral pests without a prolonged study.  No matter how smart the rabbits are, without knowledge of biowarfare protocols that's probably the end of rabbit sapience.  (So I'm guessing you don't want the rabbits to be in Australia.)

Comment: Did someone say White Blindness?

Comment: Worth noting that sapience was a factor in turning our own species from the bottom of the food chain into an apex predator and let us spread explosively across the globe. Imagine what it would do to an actual fast breeder like rabbits.

Answer (score 4):

Since the rabbits would likely become aware of their hunters and how to avoid them, and since rabbit gestation periods last only about a month, the rabbit population would likely explode over the next year or two.

Once crops are eaten, a few lucky country folk encounter communicating rabbits wielding sticks, and rabbit societies begin forming in the deepest parts of the forest, news coverage would likely reach worldwide attention and the rabbits would become famous. In fact, the rabbits would likely evolve in a process similar to humans, but of course it would take millions of years.

I'd imagine this would lead to a future in which rabbits and humans have evolved together and created a really weird society, but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 1):

**Never or Almost Instantly, Depending on how Fashionable the Rabbits are.**

Humans have a hellaciously hard time telling if whole species are sapient.  Look at whales, dolphins, some (all?) of the great apes, certain parrots.... We just can't decide.  About whole species.  Who are collectively doing sapient things.  A single warren of sapient rabbits is one housing development or parking lot away from extinction.  Wild rabbit warrens follow a boom-and-bust population cycle anyway, so even a successful sapient rabbit warren would (unless they get together to start murdering every predator around AND learn some hygiene to stave of disease) just attract more and more predators.

Meanwhile as this goes on the local humans might think the local rabbits are "smarter" than normal, but certainly not sapient.  They don't talk! They don't build cities! (at least nothing humans can see, warrens being underground.  And even then they're unlikely to be so much better humans would notice.)  They don't paint or do anything "civilized"! They don't talk!  They're just animals.  Smart animals, but not sapient.  Remember a suddenly-sapientwarren (barring hand-waving) isn't going to also have complex societal things like modern governments, research divisions, militaries, embassies, or  whatever.  They're going to be the rabbit equivalent of humans at 100,000bc.  Except your bunnies can't hold spears because they have thumbs and don't need clothes! So it would take only the most extraordinary luck and a huge amount of time for humans to realize the rabbits are sapient.

**Unless**

Your rabbits, for cultural reasons outside "to ID ourselves to humans" (after all, we can't spot sapient species so why expect rabbits to ID us?) use dyes or personal ornamentation.  To my knowledge none of the other possibly-sapient species on the planet do this.  Decorate nests yes, decorate themselves, no.  If rabbits were suddenly seen/caught wearing intricately nibbled wooden paw-rings with regular or animal designs, or with woad running in patters all over their fur, you'd get the media and scientists interested pretty quickly.  From there it'd be easy to realize these rabbits are somehow chimp-smart. (some sort of Rabbit expert or studies should get there fast.)  Then sapience is a shorter leap to make, because you can obviously see the warren is miles more intelligent than the rest of the species.

Answer (score 1):

**They wouldn't**

The sudden sapience onset would probably be dismissed as a parasite. This is because there is a reason that rabbits aren't sapient, and that reason is food. The rabbits would guzzle through their fat stores at near-human rates, but would still feel full after a rabbit-sized meal. Eventually, this would catch up to them, and they'd starve to death on a full stomach